# Tasks work with one method. How to prevent code duplication?

Tags: c#, task, code-duplication

Lets suppose there are two Tasks:

```
Task.Run(() => {
    while (!this.isCanceled)
        DoOperation(obj);
});
```

and

```
Task.Run(() => {
    foreach(var obj in objects)   // Another objects' subset
        while(!this.isCancelled)
            DoOperation(obj);
});
```

And `DoOperation(Foo obj)` implementation:

```
DoOperation(Foo obj)
{
    if (obj.IsBar && obj.IsFoo)
        obj.MakeSad();
    else
        obj.MakeHappy();
}
```

We can lock method `DoOperation` and everything should be good, but this approach has some performance negatives sides. Moreover with the `DoOperation` method can work lots of tasks at a time.
The second approach is to duplicate the whole method into each task. But it's even worse.

So the question is how to avoid locking and prevent code-duplication?

Answer (score 0):

What is the critical code if your operation? There must be one or more race conditions or there is no need to use locks at all.

If in your example it is something in the `DoSomething`, then use the lock there:

```
DoOperation(Foo obj)
{
    if (obj.IsBar && obj.IsFoo)
        obj.MakeSad();
    else {
        lock(lockObject1) {
             obj.MakeHappy();
        }
    }
}
```

This way, you are not duplicating code and all the rest if the functionalities work without being blocked. If there uses another contested block, use another lock object so that they don't block each other.

By the way,  since you are using tasks and sync programming, better user `SemaphoreSlim` for locking https://blog.cdemi.io/async-waiting-inside-c-sharp-locks/amp/

Comment: There are no problems in the ```DoSomething``` method because it deals with different ```Foo``` objects, but I think this method still can have some problems with calls on diffferent objects with different tasks
Is it possible, for example, to have a call ```obj.MakeHappy()``` where obj address in the stack is something like 0x04a1 on different reference (obj address  is 0x9a2c) dealing with multiple Tasks?